# Can EventFD be used with libEvent2?

Tags: libevent

I have multiple processes doing IPC over shared memory. I use a cross process shared EventFD to trigger when a message is available. To listen to the trigger I was using Epoll and it works fine. But I need to switch to using libEvent2 for other reasons.

I need to wait in a libEvent base loop and receive an eventFD (read) whenever the other process writes to the eventFD.

I tried adding the FD of the eventFD using bufferevent_socket_new() and event_new() but none of these work.  No callback is ever received.

Is libEvent supposed to work with eventfd?  Are there any examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this to work with event_new() using the following set of flags.

```
int flags = EV_READ | EV_WRITE | EV_ET | EV_PERSIST;
ptr = event_new(base, evfd, flags, callback, this);
```